# ProducerTemplate per endpoint URI?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am developing an application (using Camel 2.13.2) that requires sending different messages to different endpoints, using a `ProducerTemplate`. Originally we were creating a new `ProducerTemplate` per message, but after reading [this article on ProducerTemplate usage](http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html) I decided to refactor and attempt to use a single `ProducerTemplate` per camel context.

However this proved to be more complicated than it first seemed. I'm running into difficulty junit testing with a single `ProducerTemplate` (we have some complicated tests involving shutting down and starting up individual routes) and now I'm wondering if maybe I was trying to take that warning too far and that multiple `ProducerTemplate`s may be acceptable in this situation.

**Here's my question:** Is it acceptable under the recommendation made in the article linked above to create a ProducerTemplate per endpoint instance? (templates would be kept around for as long as they are needed)

**Example:** If I have endpoints `direct:processA`, `direct:processB`, and `direct:processC`, is it acceptable to do this:

```
   ProducerTemplate templateA = context.createProducerTemplate();
   ProducerTemplate templateB = context.createProducerTemplate();
   ProducerTemplate templateC = context.createProducerTemplate();

   templateA.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:processA");
   templateB.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:processB");
   templateC.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:processC");

   // in thread A
   templateA.sendBody(bodyA);

   // in thread B
   templateB.sendBody(bodyB);

   // in thread C
   templateC.sendBody(bodyC);
```

Or was it intended by the authors to only create a single `ProducerTemplate` for all endpoints:

```
   ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

   // in thread A
   template.sendBody("direct:processA", bodyA);

   // in thread B
   template.sendBody("direct:processB", bodyB);

   // in thread C
   template.sendBody("direct:processC", bodyC);
```

Comment: I've been using Camel quite actively in the past months, and from my understanding and experience, your second example is the correct one i.e. reuse the template from different threads, explicitly naming the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both. For example if you use Camel POJO producing its doing like the 1st under the covers.

- http://camel.apache.org/bean-integration.html
- http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html

Its the create new template per request that is the wrong one. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html